# Is there any way to loop through range with for/in in delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

```
type
  TRange = MIN_VALUE..MAX_VALUE;
```

Is there any way to loop through this range using for/in loop?

```
for rangeValue in TRange do 
  smth
```

Or should i loop through it like that:

```
for rangeValue := Low(TRange) to High(TRange) do
  smth
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to use for/in loops with subrange types. You will have to use the traditional for loop syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2022 ... This works in at least 10.2 onwards ...

```
program Project1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  TRange = 0..9;

begin
  for var rangeValue in [low(TRange)..high(TRange)] do write('*');

  readln;
end.
```

but what you asked for works right now in FPC ... ( https://godbolt.org/z/9zrYb9xY7 )

```
program output;

type
  TRange = 0..9;
var 
  rangeValue : integer;

begin
  for rangeValue in TRange do write('*');
end.
```